# How do I fix the "Prerequisite cannot be found for bootstrapping" warning in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

I am using:

- Visual Studio 2010 on a x64 machine
- Building a Windows Application
- Targeting .NET Framework 4 Client Profile and x86.
- I am deploying with ClickOnce.
- I have installed the "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 (7.1)".

**Here is my problem:**

On an old project, on the project properties, Publish tab, Prerequisites... button, I open [this dialog box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tx0bw8y.aspx). *All* the listed prerequisites have a yellow, triangular warning, stating, "Prerequisite cannot be found for bootstrapping". The effect is that the ClickOnce setup.exe cannot correctly install the prerequisites for users.

If I create a new, empty project from scratch, the Prerequisites box is empty.

**Here is information about various folders:**

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages` contains all the bootstrap packages.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages` contains all the bootstrap packages.

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1` did **not** have a Bootstrapper folder.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\SDK` that has nothing in it but an empty v3.5 folder .

Environment `WindowsSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\`

Registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper\4.0\Path` = `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages`

**Here is what I have tried:**

I have tried copying the Bootstrapper folder from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\` to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1` but that did not make a difference.

I have tried copying the Bootstrapper folder from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\SDK\v4.0`. That did not make a difference.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- make the prerequisites with [bootstrapper manifest generator](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1567)
- then add them into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
  SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages folder

If it works please notify by comment..