# Prerequisite could not be found for bootstrapping (All listed)

Tags: vb.net, setup-deployment, bootstrapping, prerequisites

Like with [Wallys Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220383/how-do-i-fix-the-prerequisite-cannot-be-found-for-bootstrapping-warning-in-vis) I cannot seem to fix the problem with broken links in my prerequisites list.  I am deploying a vb.net desktop application using clickonce but the required prerequisites are showing an exclamation warning icon.  I have checked the location in the registry and ensured the packages are in the correct folder (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages) but each time I close and re-open the studio, I do not see the added packages and there are only .Net v2.0 to 3.5 listed. (with warnings)

I experienced this in the past when changing development machine but once I added the packages to the correct folder they appeared in the prerequisites list.

This problem occured after installing vs2010 SP1.  I removed the SP and re-installed the studio, everything else seems ok.

Has anybody else encountered this problem and can you help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I eventually fixed it.

Uninstalled everything related to .Net and vs2008/vs2010.
Cleaned the program files directory to remove all related to visual studio
Logged in as Administrator
Ran full install.
All prerequisites now visible for deployment.