# How to fix Setup project Prerequisites warning

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8, setup-project, prerequisites

When I go to the "Setup Property Pages" in a Visual Studio Setup project and view the Prerequisites, I see a warning:

> Prerequisite could not be found for bootstrapping

I did the following things:

1. Added a new folder in: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages" with my package
2. Restarted VS2010
3. (Even rebooted my pc)

Warning is still visible on that package.
Next I've added a .VSBootstrapperManifest file in the Packages directory ( C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages )

Restarted VS2010 again but that didn't help either, same with reboot.

Any suggestion what could be wrong?
This worked on my Win7 x64 machine, but this doesn't seem to work anymore on my Win8 Pro x64.

Thanks in advance.

**update:**

When I open the Product.xml file from my package I see these XML lines:

```
  <InstallChecks>
    <RegistryCheck Property="FoxProOleDbInstalled" Key="HKCR\CLSID\{...-..-..}\InprocServer32" />
  </InstallChecks>
```

When I search that key {...-..-..} in my registry I cannot find it at the location HKCR\CLSID{...-..-..}
But I can find it at this location:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ **Wow6432Node** \CLSID\ {...-..-..}

Can I just add another line inside the InstallChecks-tag in the Product.xml ?
How will the RegistryCheck tags be checked in that file (AND? OR?)
(I think all InstallChecks need to be true but I'm not sure, the documentation is not so clear: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229432(v=vs.80).aspx )

Comment: Did you try all the solutions given in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220383/how-do-i-fix-the-prerequisite-cannot-be-found-for-bootstrapping-warning-in-vis?lq=1 Also have a look at this link: http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/557250-VS-2010-Prerequiste-could-not-be-found-for-bootstrapping

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing windows 8 store/metro apps in "windows 8 pro".
Use visual studio 2012 instead of vs2010.It will work.

Comment: Working with VS2010 as written in the post.